# How to handle ArrayIndexOutofBounds while printing array in snake form

Tags: java

I have a requirement to print the matrix in a snake form. So for this matrix, the output should be:

My question is that this code throws ArrayIndexOutofBounds. How can I handle that to avoid this?

```
int[][] mat= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        int row=mat.length;
        int col=mat[0].length-1;

        int c=col;
        int r=0;

        while(r < row) {
            for(int j=c;j>=0;j--) {
            //  System.out.print("r: " + r);
            //  System.out.print(" " + mat[r][j]);


            }
            r=r+1;
            for(int j=0;j<=c;j++) {
        //  System.out.print("r: " + r);
            //System.out.print(" " + mat[r][j]);
            }
            r=r+1;


        }
```

3 2 1 4 5 6 9 8 7

Comment: Why not learn how to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have gone about it:

```
int[][] mat= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int row=0;
while(row < mat.length) {

   if(row%2 == 0){ //if an even row, go right to left
      int col = mat[0].length - 1;
      while(col >= 0) { System.out.print(mat[row][col]); col--; } 
   }else {
      int col = 0;
      while(col < mat[0].length) { System.out.print(mat[row][col]); col++; } 
   }
   row++;
}
```

where you are going wrong is in incrementing r inside the loop and not checking if it's still less then the length before printing.
you can also add this check to your code for it to start working:

```
.
.
r=r+1;
if(r >= row)
   break;
for(int j=0;j<=c;j++) {
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the second line says:

```
int row=mat.length;
```

Because array indexes start at 0, you should change it to:

```
int row=mat.length-1;
```

to avoid getting an exception when calling `mat[row]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing so many variables you can just set up the for loops which first determine if we are starting at the end or beginning of the row and then iterate over all the integers.

```
        int[][] mat= {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};    
        for(int row = 0; row < mat.length; row++){
            if(row%2 == 0){
                for(int col = mat[row].length -1; col >= 0; col--){
                    System.out.print(mat[row][col] + " ");
                }                
            }else{
                for(int col = 0; col < mat[row].length; col++){
                    System.out.print(mat[row][col] + " ");
                }                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  It is important to take the row length to allow for ragged arrays.

```java
      int[][] mat = { { 1, 2, 3
            }, { 4, 5, 6
            }, { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
            }, { 12, 13
            }, { 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
            }

      };

      for (int r = 0; r < mat.length; r++) {
         if (r % 2 == 0) {
            for (int c = mat[r].length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
               System.out.print(" " + mat[r][c]);
            }
         }
         else {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat[r].length; c++) {
               System.out.print(" " + mat[r][c]);
            }
         }

      }
```

Note that if you want to snake left to right, then modify it to use `r % 2 == 1`.  If you want to go bottom up, change your outer loop to start at the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because r becomes 3 (r=r+1) on second iteration and you try to access mat[**3**][2] (ie. you are accessing the values of fourth row which is not available)

```
for(int row = 0; row < mat.length; row++){
   if(row%2 == 0)  { 
   // print the elements in reverse order
   }
   else {
   //print the elements as in given matrix
   }
}
```

Thus all your odd rows' (ie. 1st, 3rd, 5th row..) elements will be printed in reverse order and even rows' elements will be printed as in given matrix